# Producer lost some message on kafka restart

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka Client : 0.11.0.0-cp1
Kafka Broker :

On Kafka broker rolling restart, our application lost some messages while sending to broker. I believe with rolling restart there should not be any loss of message. These are the producer (Using Producer with asynchronous send() and not using callback/future etc) settings we are using :

```
val acksConfig: String = "all",
val retriesConfig: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
val retriesBackOffConfig: Int = 1000,
val batchSize: Int = 32768,
val lingerTime: Int = 1,
val maxBlockTime: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
val requestTimeOut: Int = 420000,
val bufferMemory: Int = 33_554_432,
val compressionType: String = "gzip",
val keySerializer: Class<StringSerializer> = StringSerializer::class.java,
val valueSerializer: Class<ByteArraySerializer> = ByteArraySerializer::class.java
```

I am seeing these exceptions in the logs

```
2019-03-19 17:30:59,224 [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender] [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] (Sender.java:511) WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - Got error produce response with correlation id 1105790 on topic-partition catapult_on_entitlement_updates_prod-67, retrying (2147483643 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION
```

But log says retry attempt left, i am curious why didnt it retry then? Let me know if anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note:

1. What is the replication factor of the topic you are producing and what is the required number of min.insync.replicas?
2. What do you mean by "producer lost some messages". The producer if it cannot successfully produce to #min.insync.replicas brokers it will throw an exception and fail (for synchronous production). It is up to the producer/ client to retry in case of failure (synchronous or asynchronous production).

Comment: Check this out and let me know-https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/issues/846                              Also,try increasing the session timeout value

Comment: @Vassilis Thanks for the answer.  1.) min.insync.replicas is 2 and replication factor is 3. 2.) So in this case it should keep retrying right? When i say lost of messages, i meant consumer never recieved some messages it should, so i assumed we lost. I dont see any other exception i posted above.

Comment: @cosmichema I believe session timeout holds for consumers.

Comment: @mdev Try using the synchronous send and in case of any problem with the production (e.g. less that 2 brokers alive) the sender (the client) should receive an exception (https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#min-insync-replicas). Also define the timeout. It is up to the client to code the retry logic, there is no automatic retry.

Comment: @mdev internally the producer may retry timeouts (or other errors), but there is no guarantee of success, and as a result the client should have its own retry logic. Try using the standard kafka console consumer to check if the message is indeed produced or not. If you do not receive an exception then it should.